# Scaffolding aspnet webapi with jquery grid and unit testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I've an ASPNET MVC4 project using WebApi, EF5 Code First and Repository and Unit of Work patterns.

I'd like to know if someone knows a scaffolder to scaffold the controllers and views, but instead of using something like [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/), I'd like the views to have a script associated with jquery requesting something from the webapi controllers, and not returning a View from the controllers.
And if possible scaffold unit testing as well.

What's the best jquery grid (open source and free) out there?

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Comment: You might want to look at http://knockoutjs.com as an addition to jquery.  Doesn't help with the scaffolding but I think it's a natural with WebAPI.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it, but as of today there is no SPA scaffolder (removed from RC as they didn't make it for the release) and I didn't find any scaffolder for webapi/ASPNET MVC4 so far